# PHP Datagrid class - Supporting sort, print, search, open source

Tags: php, search, sorting, printing, datagrid

I am a newcomer in the PHP world, and I am building a relatively simple application. Basically, I need to present some data from a MySQL database in a datagrid. I have been looking for a very simple datagrid, which should support, at least, sorting, printing, searching and it must be based in open source.

I have seen a lot of them in Internet, but most of them are commercial, outdated, or they do not support some of the features I aforementioned.

May I know what are your preferences for Datagrids in PHP ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the only actively maintained datagrid for PHP is still the one from [phpgrid.com](http://phpgrid.com).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[tutorials link](http://phpgrid.com/example/)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for [PHP Grid Framework](http://www.phpgrid.org).

I think its little late but you can also check this [PHP Grid Framework](http://www.phpgrid.org) solution. It's pretty simple to use than others. It has a free version too.

[image: PHP Grid Framework howto]

Watch 1 Minute Demo:

[image: PHP Grid Framework demo]

Answer (score -1):

I like this one: http://zfdatagrid.com/

Comment: zfdatagrid no longer exists.